# Loop all values in column A to find all matches in column B

Tags: excel, vba

My code finds all internal connections in external workbook, finds all hidden sheets.

What I would like to achieve thanks to that values is to remove all hidden sheets which are not sources for any other sheet in workbook.

I know that it should be done with nested loop, but I have problems building that.

[image: 1]

```
For Each c In wbmacro.Sheets("Link Sheet").Range("D2:D10")
    For Each rc In wbmacro.Sheets("Link Sheet").Range("C2:C10")
        If c.Value <> rc.Value Then
            wbtarget.Sheets(c).Delete
        End If
    Next
Next
```

I tested all three responses, nothing happens in code run.

Full code to review:

```
Sub a()

Dim xSheet As Worksheet
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCell As Range
Dim xCount As Long
Dim xLinkArr() As String
Dim wbmacro As Workbook
Dim wbtarget As Workbook
Dim strfile As String
Dim strpath As String
Dim filename As String
Dim hsheet As String

Set wbmacro = ActiveWorkbook
filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xlsx")

Set wbtarget = Workbooks.Open(filename, UpdateLinks:=0)
        
On Error Resume Next

For Each xSheet In wbtarget.Sheets
    
    Set xRg = xSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then GoTo LblNext
    For Each xCell In xRg
        If InStr(1, xCell.Formula, "!") > 0 Then
            xCount = xCount + 1
            ReDim Preserve xLinkArr(1 To 2, 1 To xCount)
            xLinkArr(1, xCount) = xCell.Address(, , , True)
            xLinkArr(2, xCount) = "'" & xCell.Formula
       End If
    Next

LblNext:
Next

If xCount > 0 Then
    wbmacro.Activate
    wbmacro.Sheets("Link Sheet").Activate
    Range("A1").Resize(, 3).Value = Array("Location", "Reference", "Reference Sheet Name")
    Range("A2").Resize(UBound(xLinkArr, 2), UBound(xLinkArr, 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(xLinkArr)
    Columns("A:D").AutoFit
Else
    MsgBox "No links were found within the active workbook.", vbInformation
End If

x = 2
For Each ws In wbtarget.Worksheets
    If ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden Then
        wbmacro.Sheets("Link Sheet").Cells(x, 4) = ws.Name
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next ws

wbmacro.Activate
Columns("A:C").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$758").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

Dim rc As Range
For Each c In wbmacro.Sheets("Link Sheet").Range("D2:D10").Cells
    ' The default behaviour is to delete the sheet
    bDeleteSheet = True
    For Each rc In wbmacro.Sheets("Link Sheet").Range("C2:C10").Cells
        If c.Value = rc.Value Then
            ' If you find the sheet name then it is used
            ' Do NOT delete it
            bDeleteSheet = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If bDeleteSheet Then wbtarget.Sheets(c).Delete
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please explain how your screenshot relates to the code?

Comment: In column C I have sheet names which are sources for other sheets in workbook. In column D I have sheets which are hidden in workbook. What I would like to have is to remove all hidden sheets which names are not given in column C.

Answer (score 1):

loop once and use `Application.Match()` to see if it exists:

```
For Each c In wbmacro.Sheets("Link Sheet").Range("D2:D10")
    If IsError(Application.Match(c,wbmacro.Sheets("Link Sheet").Range("C2:C10"),0)) and Len(c) > 0 then
        wbtarget.Sheets(c).Delete
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Why not remove the `Len` check and wrap the `Sheets(c).Delete` with `On Error Resume Next`? :)

Comment: I am getting error in vba type mismatch after running this code, line 4

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
Dim bDeleteSheet As Boolean

For Each c In wbmacro.Sheets("Link Sheet").Range("D2:D10").Cells
    ' The default behaviour is to delete the sheet
    bDeleteSheet = True
    For Each rc In wbmacro.Sheets("Link Sheet").Range("C2:C10").Cells
        If c.Value = rc.Value Then
            ' If you find the sheet name then it is used
            ' Do NOT delete it
            bDeleteSheet = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If bDeleteSheet Then wbtarget.Sheets(c).Delete
Next
```

Edit:
I added `.Cells` in two lines: In my experience omitting this caused some issues for me in the past.

I also have to mention that this is by far not the most efficient or dynamic code, but it follows your logic and it's a good starting point.

In reality in a small code like this, any optimisation will make very little difference to the execution time of the code. However, as your code grows and/or you have loop through more cells, there are ways to optimise your code.

- To make your code more efficient a general rule of thumb is to minimise any interaction with the excel application and to achieve that you google subjects like "how to read my range in memory in vba"
- To make your code more dynamic google subjects like "how to reference ranges more dynamically in excel vba". As an example instead of hard-coding the row number `10` in your range, you can work it out like this:

```
Dim lLastRow as Long
lLastRow = wbmacro.Sheets("Link Sheet").Range("C" & Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

This is the same as going all the way down to last cell in column C and pressing Ctrl+Up, which will take you to last used cell in that columns and then reading the row number.

Now you can reference the range like this:

```
wbmacro.Sheets("Link Sheet").Range("C2:C" & lLastRow)
```

Note that (from the image above) `lLastRow` now has the value 3, which means that your code will not loop 7 more times unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

Scott & dwirony beat me to it but I got there while they were posting here's the code I came up with:

```
Sub Test()

Dim Ref As Range
  
For Each Ref In Range("HiddenSheets").Cells
 
   With Application
        On Error Resume Next
        Err.Clear
        Result = .WorksheetFunction.Match(Ref.Value, Range("References"), 0)
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            .DisplayAlerts = False
           MsgBox "Deleting: " & Ref.Value, vbOKOnly, _
                  "Delete: Confirmation"
           ' wbtarget.Sheets(Ref.Value).Delete
            .DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
        
   End With
   
Next Ref

End Sub 'Test
```

Note: I set up two Dynamic Named References so it doesn't matter how many items are in Column C: Name "References" or Column D: Name "HiddenSheets" I've also commented out the Delete statement and used a message box to check what was going on. Note the Use of DisplayAlerts so you don't get delete dialog boxes to click on. You'll also have to add back in your fully qualified references for the workbooks to delete the sheets from.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I think that it works perfectly now. I mixed your codes:

```
Sub b()
Dim c As Range
Dim filename As String
Dim lLastRow1 As Long
Dim lLastRow2 As Long

Set wbmacro = ActiveWorkbook
filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xlsx")
Set wbtarget = Workbooks.Open(filename, UpdateLinks:=0)
lLastRow1 = wbmacro.Sheets("Link Sheet").Range("C" & Columns.Count).End(xlUp).row
lLastRow2 = wbmacro.Sheets("Link Sheet").Range("D" & Columns.Count).End(xlUp).row
Dim Ref As Range
wbmacro.Activate

For Each Ref In wbmacro.Sheets("Link Sheet").Range("D2:D" & lLastRow2).Cells

With Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Clear
    result = .WorksheetFunction.Match(Ref.Value, Range("C2:C" & lLastRow1), 0)
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        .DisplayAlerts = False
       MsgBox "Deleting: " & Ref.Value, vbOKOnly, _
              "Delete: Confirmation"
        wbtarget.Sheets(Ref.Value).Delete
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    
 End With

  Next Ref


 End Sub
```